# JavaScript Whitespace Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, formatting, whitespace

Why does this cause a syntax error for the return statement:

```
var FOO = (function($)
{
    return
    {      
        init: function()
        {

        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```
var FOO = (function($)
{
    return {      
        init: function()
        {

        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi technically that question would be a duplicate of this one, since it came first ;)  But the emphasis and "searchability" are different (e.g. I don't want this question deleted)

Comment: @drzaus: Duplicate closures don't need to strictly follow a temporal order - we have many canonical questions that were asked later but have higher-quality answers :-) Notice that I only wanted to link that related, very relevant post (it's not an exact dupe), I didn't (vote to) close this question. Also, closed questions don't get deleted.

Comment: @Bergi from [the SO explanation of dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) > "Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted"; unsure if it actually happens, but figured I'd "vote" to keep the question (since I found this one rather than the 'canonical')

Comment: @drzaus: Closed questions with no upvotes, no answers and few views are automatically deleted after some time. This one fulfills neither of the requirements for that :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not about the whitespace, it's about automatic semicolon insertion by JavaScript.

ECMAScript specification says

> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty
>   statement, variable statement,
>   expression statement, do-while
>   statement, continue statement, break
>   statement, return statement, and throw
>   statement) must be terminated with
>   semicolons. Such semicolons may always
>   appear explicitly in the source text.
>   For convenience, however, such
>   semicolons may be omitted from the
>   source text in certain situations.
>   These situations are described by
>   saying that semicolons are
>   automatically inserted into the source
>   code token stream in those situations.

This means that your code

```
var FOO = (function($)
{
    return
    {      
        init: function()
        {

        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

gets translated as

```
var FOO = (function($)
{
    return; // <- JavaScript will insert a semicolon here.

    {      
        init: function()
        {

        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

So FOO will be undefined after the function is executed.

For your other code, <strike>JS won't insert any semicolon and it will work correctly</strike> JS will insert semicolon after your literal object and it should work fine. [EDIT: Correction as pointed out by kagnax]

This means that you should always terminate your statements with semicolon. Letting JS engine insert semicolon can introduce very subtle bugs, which would take hours to debug. You can use a tool like [JSLint](http://jslint.com) which will warn you of missing semicolons.

Comment: Actually, for his "other code" JS **will** insert semicolon, but only after object literal — as explained in the section of specs you quoted — *ReturnStatement*s are candidates for ASI :)

Comment: kangax, I didn't notice that his other literal was also missing a semicolon. I will update the answer.

Comment: Some convinience, huh? I did not realize that Javascript will mess around with my code making such subtle but profound modifications. I do not want this 'convinience'. +1 for the taken to bascics explanation

Comment: Another reason to include the opening brace on the same line as the keyword =)